# switch executes both cases in options menu

Tags: android, switch-statement

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.item1: fukncijaD();
        case R.id.item20: funkcijaOceni();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

//here is the xml for the menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <item android:title="Зачувај" 
          android:id="@+id/item1"></item>
         <item android:id="@+id/item20" android:title="Оцени"></item>
         <item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="Пост на ФБ"></item>

    </menu>
```

When I check the value in `case R.id.item1: fukncijaD();` it goes as it should with `funckcijaD()`, and then continues with the second case as if there were no cases...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put break

```
switch(item.getItemId())
 {
 case R.id.item1:fukncijaD();break;
 case R.id.item20:funkcijaOceni();break;

 }
```